# How to enable and disable cronjobs using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, cron

**We'd like to enable/disable the following crontab:**

```
*/1 * * * * bash /home/scripts/mywork.sh
```

Already tried to disable using (looks like I cleared my crontabs with that :/):

```
crontab -l | sed "/^[^#].*bash /home/scripts/mywork.sh/s/^/#/" | crontab -
```

...and get the issue:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 16: extra characters after command
```

How to fix it? :)

*I am new to stackoverflow, feel free to comment so I can improve my asking skills.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape '/' characters in your sed command...

```
sed "/^[^#].*bash \/home\/scripts\/mywork.sh/s/^/#/"
```